# Spring : how to expose SimpMessagingTemplate bean to root context ?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, websocket, applicationcontext

I'm developing a Java webapp with Spring as the main framework (Spring core, Spring mvc, Spring security, Spring data, Spring websocket are notably used).

Declaring a `message-broker` in a Spring context like this provides a `SimpMessagingTemplate` bean to the context :

```
<websocket:message-broker>
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/stomp">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic,/queue"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

I have to put this tag in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` (not `applicationContext.xml`), otherwise clients will get a 404 when trying to connect to the websocket (on initial page load).

However, since this tag which provides the `SimpMessagingTemplate` bean (to send messages to connected clients) is not available in the root context, when a service (scanned by the root context) sends a websocket message, the `SimpMessagingTemplate` bean cannot be autowired (classical `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`).

Previously, the `<websocket:message-broker>` tag was in `applicationContext.xml` and `dispatcher-servlet.xml` was importing `applicationContext.xml` and everything was working fine - however I found out to my surprise that this was wrong when I recently used a `SessionRegistry` to modify arbitrary user sessions.

Indeed, since the `DispatcherServlet` was explicitely importing the root context, which is already inherited implicitely, the `SessionRegistry` bean was created twice, leading to unexpected behaviours (there are several posts on SO that depict this common mistake, usually users want to get a list of all principals but get empty lists due to the `SessionRegistry` bean duplication and find out about this).

So to fix this I removed the

```
<import resource="applicationContext.xml"/>
```

from the dispatcher-servlet.xml, but since then :

- either I put the `<websocket:messagebroker>...</>` tag in the dispatcher-servlet.xml, in which case connections to websocket are successful but services cannot autowire `SimpMessagingTemplate`
- or I put the `<websocket:messagebroker>...</>` tag in `applicationContext.xml`, in which case clients cannot connect to websocket.
- (or I go back to the previous version, where `DispatcherServlet` imports `ApplicationContext`, which breaks `SessionRegistry` - nope)

What is the solution to this probably rather common problem ? The `DispatcherServlet` can access beans from the root context but not vice-versa, so how should I work this out ?

Comment: I experimented with putting everything from applicationContext.xml into dispatcher-servlet, but then spring-security can't use authentication beans that were declared in the root context, which is basically just the same issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a dirty solution. I don't like it, but given the lack of answers on SO (see also : [Dispatcher-servlet cannot map to websocket requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012193/dispatcher-servlet-cannot-map-to-websocket-requests) ), as well as from current and former colleagues, I had to go forward with the project and implemented a dirty fix.

The dirty fix is to `Autowire` the `SimpMessagingTemplate` in Controller and Scheduled classes (all scanned by the `dispatcher-servlet`, where the `websocket tag` is declared), and to pass the `SimpMessagingTemplate` as a parameter to service methods (declared in the `root context`).

This solution is not transparent (the `SimpMessagingTemplate` should be autowired directly in services ideally) but it definitely fixes the problem.

Comment: That's a pain. I'm using a similar solution: use @PostConstruct and then set it to Service.